# Xcode iOS 7 Issue with Delete Row Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a Table view. When the user swipes to the left the delete button appears and he is able to remove this entry. But now I've made some strange experiences with the row animation. When the user then clicks on the delete button it stays there but the normal cell is moved. After the  cell content view has disappeard the delete button exits also.

What's the problem here?

```
[[eventDataDictionary objectForKey:key] removeObject:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Thanks and best regards from Germany,
Chris

Comment: I am curious.. do you really need to add all this code? The swipe and delete animation should happen with as little code as this - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need beginUpdates, endUpdates. `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` has its own animation parameter. Just remove the begin~end end try again.